# How to call a slot, that belongs to a QThread, within that same QThread?

Tags: linux, qt, signals-slots, qthread, qprocess

I have a QThread that starts an external Linux binary. I use connect() to call a slot(), which is part of the QThread, whenever I get an output from that external Linux binary. This seems not to work for me. Can anyone tell me what is wrong in the below code?

```
class ThreadPowerSubSystem : public QThread
{

public:
ThreadPowerSubSystem(){ }

private slots:
void checkForTwoSecPress()
{
    qWarning("button pressed");
}

private:


void run()
{
    QProcess *powerProcess = new QProcess();
    powerProcess->start("/home/testApp/button");
    connect(powerProcess, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(checkForTwoSecPress()));
    exec();
}
};
```

Also I need to call a function to display a dialog inside that slot. Can anyone show me an example on how to do it?

Comment: Do not inherit from QThread, unless you want to change how Qt manages threads. I recommend reading this article and following its method of using QThread: https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/

Comment: Why do you use threads, anyway? Usually you can use `QProcess` in the main thread without problems, as it operates asynchronously.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight you are not constructive. It is not necessary to follow your guideline at all. Way of implementing multithreading depends on exact situation. There are no mandatory templates like "create an worker and call moveToThread". Stop imposing this thing... Anyway, your comment is completely not related to the question

Comment: 1) execute() is a static function and does not do anything with powerProcess. thus readyRead() will never be emitted. 2) You cannot show dialogs outside the main UI thread, you would need to trigger it in the main thread e.g. via a cross-thread signal/slot connection.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll try with start. I am aware of UI threads can not be accessed from another thread and that's why I am looking for a way to do that? Can you show me an example with signals and slots?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld When i use start() to call the external binary, it never launches that binary.

Comment: @SaZ, so what you're saying is that I'm not entitled to an opinion?! And you state MY comment is not constructive! I wasn't imposing anything and they are not my guidelines. This is also the view of some of the Qt developers. Perhaps you would be better off making a useful comment to the OP, rather than simply criticising the opinions of others.

Comment: You comment begins with words "DO NOT...". If you want to point on something, you should write "There are good practice in multithreading with Qt <your link>". Comments are for discussion. Answers are for something usefull.